# Fitting video length to audio with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I have two files. One of them is a video with a set duration of 20 seconds. The other is an audio track that I don't know the length of it. If I add -shortest then if audio length is longer than 20 seconds it will be cut. If I don't then if audio length is shorter than 20 seconds it still goes on for 20 seconds.

Comment: So you want to adjust the video duration to always match the audio duration?

Comment: Yes, pretty much.